# Search a keyword in a file and then add line after finding keyword in a body using perl or sed

Tags: perl, awk, sed

I was trying to search a keyword (cell (edita)) in a lengthy file (input.txt) which has above 10000 lines and different cell names like cell(noedit) , cell (editb) .And then I should search for pin (q) (2nd occurance )and add line "class" , pin (yz) (2nd occurance ) and add "board". **I should not manipulate cell (noedit) block** .

MY input.txt

```
        cell (edita)  {
            test{
                 pin (Q) {
                 zzzzzz
                }
                pin (yz) {
                zzzzz 
                }
                }
                 pin (Q) {
                 add
                 }
                 pin (yz) {
                 add 
             }
        }
        cell (noedit)  {
            test{
                 pin (Q) {
                 zzzzzz
                }
                pin (yz) {
                zzzzz 
                }
                }
                 pin (Q) {
                 add
                 }
                 pin (yz) {
                 add 
             }
        }
    cell (editb)  {
            test{
                 pin (Q) {
                 zzzzzz
                }
                pin (yz) {
                zzzzz 
                }
                }
                 pin (Q) {
                 add
                 }
                 pin (yz) {
                 add 
             }
        }
```

my output.txt should look like this

```
cell (edita)  {
            test{
                 pin (Q) {
                 zzzzzz
                }
                pin (yz) {
                zzzzz 
                }
                }
                 pin (Q) {
                 "class";
                 add
                 }
                 pin (yz) {
                 board;
                 add 
             }
        }
        cell (noedit)  {
            test{
                 pin (Q) {
                 zzzzzz
                }
                pin (yz) {
                zzzzz 
                }
                }
                 pin (Q) {
                 add
                 }
                 pin (yz) {
                 add 
             }
        }
    cell (editb)  {
            test{
                 pin (Q) {
                 zzzzzz
                }
                pin (yz) {
                zzzzz 
                }
                }
                 pin (Q) {
                 "class";
                 add
                 }
                 pin (yz) {
                 board ;
                 add 
             }
        }
```

I have tried writing sed which only does if file has from pin (i.e no cell (a) line) ,and even it manipulates only 2nd occurance

sed '/\s*pin\s(Q)/{p;s/.*/1/;H;g;/^(\n1){2}$/s//        class;/p;d}' input.txt
sed '/\s*pin\s(y)/{p;s/.*/1/;H;g;/^(\n1){2}$/s//        board;/p;d}' input.txt

Please can any one help me out to serach for cell and then manipulate.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like you are trying to parse a [DSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language)? I would recommend using [Perl 6 grammars](https://docs.perl6.org/language/grammar_tutorial) in that case.

Comment: Thanks @ Håkon Hægland I will surely try .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '1{x;s/^/;,/;x};/^cell (a)/I,/^}/{/pin (q)/I{x;s/;/&q/;/;q\{2\},/{x;p;s/pin.*/class ;/;x};x};/pin (y)/I{x;s/,/&y/;/,y\{2\}$/{x;p;s/pin.*/board ;/;x};x}}' file
```

Prime the hold space with a couple of delimiters (`;` for `pin (q)` counter and `,` for `pin (y)` counter). Restrict the processing to the `cell (a)`. Each time a `pin (q)` or a `pin (y)` is encountered, add one to its respective counter in the hold space. If the counter is 2 (may be any number) print the current line and then amend the current line to reflect the appended string.

EDIT:
Since the original question has changed:

```
sed '/cell ([^)]*)/{h;x;s/^/;:,/;x};G;/cell (edit[ab])/{/pin (q)/I{x;s/;/&q/;/;q\{2\}:/{x;P;s/\S.*/"class";/;x};x};/pin (yz)/I{x;s/:/&y/;/:y\{2\},/{x;P;s/\S.*/board/;x};x}};P;d' file
```

Comment: Thanks a ton ,its working .I tried for 3rd pin say pin (z) ,please check the below command and let me know whether its correct?                                ----- sed '1{x;s/^/;,/;x};/^cell (a)/I,/^}/{/pin (q)/I{x;s/;/&q/;/;q\{2\},/{x;p;s/pin.*/class ;/;x};x};/pin (y)/I{x;s/;/&y/;/;y\{2\},/{x;p;s/pin.*/board ;/;x};x};/pin (z)/I{x;s/,/&z/;/,z\{2\}$/{x;p;s/pin.*/board2 ;/;x};x}}' file ----. @potong

Comment: @Anthonyj each pin needs its own area in the hold space i.e. a delimiter. For pin q I used `;` for pin y I used `,` so for pin z use say `:`. Then later on when you are counting look for `:` and append `z` after it. Hope this helps.

Comment: @ potong Thanks again it worked . I was trying to write for file which has additional cells i.e cell(b), cell (c) whose body is same as cell (a) . I listed all cell names in list file and then tried 
-------                                                                                                   foreach c (`cat list`){
sed -i '1{x;s/^/;,/;x};/\s*cell (${c})/I,/^}/{/pin (q)/I{x;s/;/&q/;/;q\{2\},/{x;p;s/pin.*/class ;/;x};x};/pin (y)/I{x;s/,/&y/;/,y\{2\}$/{x;p;s/pin.*/board ;/;x};x}}' file 
end . '  BUT its not working Please help me to know where im wrong . Thanks in advance

Comment: @ potong Please help me how I should search for pin (ab) ,I have tried this but i am unable to search cell --- sed '/\spin\s(ab)/{p;s/.*/1/;H;g;/^\(\n1\)\{2\}$/s// class;/p;d}' file.   Thanks in advance

Comment: @Anthonyj it is not clear to me what you really want to achieve. Perhaps you should ask a new question with *one* clear objective, using the most pared down example.

Comment: @ potong I apologies for the confusion caused , I have manipulated my question Please glance once. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

idk about perl but sed is for doing s/old/new **that is all** and for anything else the standard UNIX tool to use is awk for clarity, simplicity, efficiency, portability, etc. etc. From your example it looks like this is all you're trying to do:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    map["pin (Q)"] = "class ;"
    map["pin (y)"] = "board ;"
}
{ print }
$1 == "cell" { cell = "$2" }
cell == "(a)" {
    for (pin in map) {
        if ( (s=index($0,pin)) && (++cnt[pin]==2) ) {
            print substr($0,1,s-1) map[pin]
        }
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
cell (a)  {
    test{
         pin (Q) {
         zzzzzz
        }
        pin (y) {
        zzzzz
        }
        }
         pin (Q) {
         class ;
         add
         }
         pin (y) {
         board ;
         add
     }
}
```

If that's not it then edit your question to clarify your requirements and provide more truly representative sample input output.

I see from your comment under @potong's answer that you want to add a 3rd pin - to do that in  the above script you just add the new mapping under the existing 2 `map[]` assignments:

```
BEGIN {
    map["pin (Q)"] = "class ;"
    map["pin (y)"] = "board ;"
    map["pin (z)"] = "board2 ;"
}
```

Comment: Please help me as I dont know much about awk , should we invoke something before using your code ? As im unable to use your code ,the output generated is same as input itself ,there is no error genertaed.Thanks in advance

Comment: No, that code will work as-is using any awk in any shell on any UNIX box and as you can see in my answer when it's run against the sample input you provided it produces the expected output you provided. If it's not doing that for you then either you aren't just using it as shown in my answer or your real input doesn't match the sample input you provided.

Comment: @ Ed Morton yeah there were extra spaces in my input so it wasnt working . Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A Perl solution. This works as a Unix filter. So if it's in a file called `transform`, you would run it as:

```
$ transform < input.txt > output.txt
```

Here's the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $in_cell_a;
my $brace_level = 0;
my ($pin_q, $pin_y);

while (<>) {
  print;
  if (/{/) {
    $brace_level++;
  }
  if (/cell \(a\)/) {
    $in_cell_a = $brace_level;
  }
  if (/(\s*)pin \(Q\)/) {
    if ($pin_q) {
      print "${1}class ;\n";
      $pin_q = 0;
    } else {
      $pin_q = 1;
    }
  }
  if (/(\s*)pin \(y\)/) {
    if ($pin_y) {
      print "${1}board ;\n";
      $pin_y = 0;
    } else {
      $pin_y = 1;
    }
  }

  if (/}/) {
    if ($brace_level == $in_cell_a) {
      $in_cell_a = 0;
    }
    $brace_level--;
  }
}
```

**Update:** Here's an updated version that uses a more data-driven approach. To add extra transformations, you just need to add them to the `$fix` variable.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $in_edit_block;
my $brace_level = 0;

my $fix = {
  'pin (Q)' => "class ;\n",
  'pin (y)' => "board ;\n",
};

my $flag;

my $fix_re = join '|', map { "\Q$_\E" } keys %$fix;

while (<>) {
  print;
  if (/{/) {
    $brace_level++;
  }
  if (/\Qcell (a)/) {
    $in_edit_block = $brace_level;
  }
  if ($in_edit_block) {
    if (my ($pad, $match) = /(\s*)($fix_re)/) {
      if ($flag->{$match}) {
        print "${pad}$fixes->{$match}";
        $flag->{$match} = 0;
      } else {
        $flag->{$match} = 1;
      }
    }
  }

  if (/}/) {
    if ($brace_level == $in_edit_block) {
      $in_edit_block = 0;
    }
    $brace_level--;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks its working  . But if I have more cells say cell (b) ,cell (c) then this will be lengthy code . Please suggest me how can I proceed with this. Thanks @ 
Dave Cross

Comment: @Anthonyj If there were more options to deal with, then I'd use a more data-driven approach. Define a hash that contains details of the various lines you need to match and the text that you need to add for them. And also to store the various flags. I might have time to look at this later today, but I can't make any promises.

Comment: @Anthonyj: Of course, that shouldn't stop you from looking at the problem yourself :-)

Comment: @ Dave Cross Im new to perl so im learning hash now so that i can get solution . And I have altered my question Please take a time to glance once Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than 1 block with cell (a) ...

```
awk '
  function addline(ind, value) {
    if(++a[ind]==2) { 
      b=$0
      sub(/[^[:blank:]].*/,"",b)
      $0=$0 "\n" b value " ;"
    }
  }
  /^cell/ {
    split("",a)
    f=0
    if(/(a)/)
      f=1
  }
  $0 ~ "pin [(]Q[)]" && f {
    addline("Q", "class")
  }
  $0 ~ "pin [(]y[)]" && f {
    addline("y", "board")
  }
1' input.txt
```

Comment: Thanks ,I want to know wheter you meant if there are more pin ? Thanks